# Custom metric for a CatBoost classifier using GPU & optuna

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, catboost, optuna

I have the following objective function to run in an Optuna hyper parameter optimization:

```
def objective(trial, data=data):

    num_train_pool = data["num_train_pool"]
    num_test_pool = data["num_test_pool"]
    true_labels_test = data["true_labels_test"]
    
    params = {'objective': 'MultiClass',
              'task_type': 'GPU',
              'logging_level': 'Verbose',
              'bootstrap_type': 'Bayesian',
              'learning_rate': trial.suggest_loguniform('learning_rate', 1e-4, 1),
              'depth': trial.suggest_int('depth', 3, 12),
              'l2_leaf_reg': trial.suggest_loguniform('l2_leaf_reg', 1e-2, 1),
              'border_count': trial.suggest_int('border_count', 32, 255)
             }
    def custom_precision(y_true, y_pred):
        true_positives = ((y_true[:, 0] == -1) & (y_pred[:, 0] == -1)).sum() + ((y_true[:, 1] == 1) & (y_pred[:, 1] == 1)).sum()
        false_positives = ((y_true[:, 0] != -1) & (y_pred[:, 0] == -1)).sum() + ((y_true[:, 1] != 1) & (y_pred[:, 1] == 1)).sum()
        return true_positives / (true_positives + false_positives + 1e-8)
    
 
    model = catboost.CatBoostClassifier(**params, custom_metric='Precision:custom_precision', random_seed=65)
    model.fit(num_train_pool, 
              verbose=0, 
              eval_set=num_test_pool,
              early_stopping_rounds=5)

    preds = model.predict(num_test_pool)
    pred_labels = np.rint(preds)
    
    score = custom_precision(true_labels_test, pred_labels)
```

This is for an unbalanced classification problem, where my class weights are as follows: {-1: 12.5, 0:0.5, 1:10}. I only really care about the obtaining a high True Positives score for classes -1 and 1, that why I wrote that custom precision function.
Also, my train Pool has a weight_vector, since not all the samples have the same "quality". My Poool looks like this:

```
num_train_pool = catboost.Pool(data=X_train,
                               label=y_train,
                               weight=y_train_weights,
                               feature_names=X_train.columns.to_list())
```

After running my optimization, I get this:

```
CatBoostError: catboost/private/libs/options/loss_description.cpp:34: Invalid metric description, it should be in the form "metric_name:param1=value1;...;paramN=valueN"
```

I think I am following CatBoost [guidelines](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/python-usages-examples#custom-loss-function-eval-metric) correctly, but can't figure out what is wrong with my code.
Any feedback?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how you are constructing your `Catboost` object. You need to reformat your string per the error message, as well as I'd suggest including your `custom_metric` in your params dict to avoid any confusion.

Try changing your `params` to:

```
params = {'objective': 'MultiClass',
          'task_type': 'GPU',
          'logging_level': 'Verbose',
          'bootstrap_type': 'Bayesian',
          'learning_rate': trial.suggest_loguniform('learning_rate', 1e-4, 1),
          'depth': trial.suggest_int('depth', 3, 12),
          'l2_leaf_reg': trial.suggest_loguniform('l2_leaf_reg', 1e-2, 1),
          'border_count': trial.suggest_int('border_count', 32, 255),
          'custom_metric': 'Precision:custom_precision=1,0,-1',
          'random_seed': 65
         }
```

and then your Catboost constructor to:

`model = catboost.CatBoostClassifier(**params)`

Comment: Can you please create a reproducible example so I can further test?